# Get time until my specified time in android

Tags: java, android, time

I am making an alarm app, that should be able to show time until next alarm. At my disposal, I have current time, and Hours:minutes:AM/PM values, and day of the week, for example 3:15 AM Tue. How can I compute this ? All I am interested in is to print it like this: 07h 35m.

What I've done, is I tried to convert it to date, then convert it back to millis, and do some math behind, but it is not working, I keep getting wrong results.

EDIT:

My problem is, that I have my time set by my custom views, like 3:15 AM Tuesday. I need to convert it to closest Date object. So for example when today is Tuesday, and it's 2:00 AM I will just edit the time, but when today is Friday, I would need to add some days and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(format.parse("3:15 AM Tue").getTime());

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        target.add(Calendar.DATE, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) < now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        target.add(Calendar.DATE, 7 - (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
    } else {
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
            target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
            target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            target.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        } else {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
                target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            } else if (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
                target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                target.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            } else {
                // target time is now!
            }
        }
    }

    long remainingTime = target.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
    final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(remainingTime);
    final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remainingTime - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr));
    String result =  String.format("%02d:%02d", hr, min);
```

Comment: Let me check this :)

Comment: I have updated it. It needs -1 in 10th line of code.

Comment: I am getting parse exception in SimpleDate Format

Comment: what do you pass to it? the pattern should be exact like "3:15 AM Tue" as you described in question content.

Comment: I am just running your code. with 3:15 AM Tue and getting Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "3:15 AM Tue"

Comment: Try to: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: You're welcome dude :) This answer may need some manipulation to work exact you want. If needed tell me to make the changes.

Comment: I will try to handle the exact parsing and do the work. Just one last thing, how can I include locale of current user ?

Comment: The `Locale` in `SimpleDateFormat`'s constructor takes the locale of input language which we force it to common english. In case of time, when you instantiate a calendar using `Calendar.getInstance()`, it takes current locale of user as default implicitly. If you want to force it a specific locale, you should pass it to `getInstance()` method like: `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.CANADA)`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String like that to actual date object, you can use a code like this:

```java
String str = "Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM";          
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = sdf1.parse(str);
System.out.println("Date Object:" + date);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a");
System.out.println("Formatted Date:" + sdf2.format(date));
```

**Edit:**

So from the edit, if I got you correctly, you want to get difference between two dates, which may be days apart and want to display the time between them in hours.

For this you may use a code like this:

```java
//1 minute = 60 seconds
//1 hour = 60 x 60 = 3600
//1 day = 3600 x 24 = 86400
public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate) { 
    //milliseconds
    long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
    System.out.println("different : " + different);

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

    long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
    different = different % daysInMilli;

    long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
    different = different % hoursInMilli;

    long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
    different = different % minutesInMilli;

    long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

    System.out.printf(
        "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
        elapsedDays, elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Sure, I have this part done. But I am struggling getting that 3:15 AM converted to closest date after current time

Comment: @LukasAnda, sorry I didn't quite get you. Great that you're done with this part. Can you explain what exactly is the problem you're facing right now.

Comment: @LukasAnda see if I got your problem correctly now.

Comment: Well that converting code seems good, but how do I get that EndDate ? I have only time and AM/PM I need to calculate the rest

Comment: What should be the endDate for your example?

Comment: Depends on current date, that's the problem. I am making an alarm app. So the closest day that it should go off based on time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182943/discussion-between-pradyumandixit-and-lukas-anda).

Answer (score 0):

Working with millis should work hands down. Keep in mind that 1000 millis = 1 sec. Do the math and then convert the result to the format you want using `SimpleDateFormat`. Also when using `dates` make sure you import `java.util.Date` and not `sql.Date`.

PS: How to get Date from your String:

```
    String TimeStringToConvertToActualDate;   //  Let's assume this is the string holding your time and you want to convert it to a date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");   // Here you should write the format you are actually using instead of this one
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
       myDate= sdf.parse(TimeStringToConvertToActualDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I was asking about the math behind that because that's what I was not able to figure out. How can I convert my pseudo date to closest next date and time

Comment: This still does not solve my problem, because I do not know the closest available day/month/year

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class and work with millis only.

The following code are changing time or days of month:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
c.add(Calendar. DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

You can get [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object using `getTime()` method when you need.